# Converting row values separated by comma with inner joins tables query

Tags: sql

I would like to convert row values separated by comma with inner joins tables query with other columns are also there.

My query is displaying like below records:

```
Name ID Services Type
xyz  1  s1       A
xyz  1  s2       A
xyz  1  s3       A
abc  2  s2       B
abc  2  s3       B
```

[image]

I'd like output like below:

```
Name, ID, Services, Type
xyz   1   s1,s2,s3  A
abc   2   s2,s3     B
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Depending on the DBMS this can be very simple or a bit complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below code:

```
create table #name (name varchar(10), id int ,type varchar(10))

insert into #name values ('XYZ',1,'A')
insert into #name values ('abc',2,'B')

create table #services (id int ,[Services] varchar(10))

insert into #services (1,'s1')
insert into #services (1,'s1')
insert into #services (1,'s2')
insert into #services (1,'s3')
insert into #services (2,'s2')
insert into #services (2,'s3')

select  Name, t.ID
  , (select s1.[Services] +',' from #Services s1 where s1.id = s.id for xml path('')) AS services
  ,[TyPe]
from #name t 
inner join #services s on s.id = t.id
```

Comment: Why have u created two tables?

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #name ( name varchar(10), id int ,type varchar(10))
```

insert into #name values ('XYZ',1,'A') insert into #name values ('abc',2,'B')

```
create table #services ( id int ,[Services] varchar(10))

insert into   #services values (1,'s1' ) 
insert into   #services values (1,'s2' )
insert into #services values (1,'s3' ) 
insert into #services values (2,'s2' ) 
insert into #services values (2,'s3' )

select * from   #name
select * from   #services


select Name, t.ID ,     
(select s1.[Services] +',' from #Services s1 where s1.id=t.id for xml
```

path('') )         AS sevices ,[TYPe] from #name t